# How to combine cells for common values in another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

What's the best way to achieve this

```
A  34    ===>      A 104

A  5     ===>      B 55

A  65    ===>

B  32    ===>

B  23    ===>
```

Refer to image for readabilty:

[image: Screenshot of Excel]

Comment: Use `SUMIF` function.

Comment: sumif would just sum it right? I want cells to combine also?

Comment: Define combining. Your image shows the sum and the criteria in different cells. They are not combine into the same cells.

Comment: A simple pivot-table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Excel 365, try the formula:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A5),y,SUMIF(A1:A5,"=" & x,B1:B5),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))
```

[image: Formula]